# calculating mean and variance of non-stationary time dependent samples

Tags: time-series, variance, mean, stationarity

I know normal procedure for calculating mean and variance which assumes that samples are iid..

I first want to know, how to calculate these two parameters if samples are time dependent but time series is stationary. Then what changes occur if time series is non-stationary. Finally how to calculate mean and variance for non-stationary time series.

Comment: The mean and variance of a non-stationary time series isn't going to be that meaningful. Probably better to calculate it for different subsets of time and compare.

Comment: @JeffreyGirard, how to decide length of time intervals? How to decide which part of time series is stationary?